# Decorator pattern loses virtual method lookups. Any good alternatives or workarounds?

Tags: java, oop, decorator, virtual-functions

### Background

I'm in the following situation:

I have an `Analyzer` type that looks roughly as follows

```
interface Analyzer {
    int computeValue();
    String performAnalysis();
}
```

implemented by something like

```
class AnalyzerImpl implements Analyzer {

    @Override
    public int computeValue() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public String performAnalysis() {
        return "Result: " + computeValue();
    }
}
```

(In my actual code, `performAnalysis` performs many computations using several different `computeValue` methods of varying complexities.)

Now I need to selectively tweak the behavior of an `Analyzer` object at runtime (or create a wrapper with the tweaked behavior).

### What I tried:

I added the tweaking-method:

```
public Analyzer tweakAnalyzer(Analyzer untweakedAnalyzer) { ... }
```

and attempted to solve it using the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
class AnalyzerDecorator implements Analyzer {
    Analyzer delegate;
    public AnalyzerDecorator(Analyzer delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public int computeValue() {
        return delegate.computeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String performAnalysis() {
        return delegate.performAnalysis();
    }
}
```

I then implemented `tweakAnalyzer` as follows:

```
public Analyzer tweakAnalyzer(Analyzer untweakedAnalyzer) {
    return new AnalyzerDecorator(untweakedAnalyzer) {
        @Override
        public int computeValue() {
            return 1337;              // tweaked value!
        }
    };
}
```

However, when doing

```
tweakAnalyzer(new AnalyzerImpl()).performAnalysis();
```

I get the *untweaked value* `Result: 5`, and not `Result: 1337` as desired.

(This is because the tweaked analyzer is not the same object as the untweaked analyzer, it's merely a wrapper, so the call to `computeValue` in `AnalyzerImpl` doesn't work as intended.)

[Full ideone.com example.](http://ideone.com/ajIKg)

### TL;DR:

I want to tweak the behavior of an object at runtime. I used the decorator pattern, but "lost" all virtual methods.

### Question:

What is the best way to solve this problem, i.e. how should I tweak the behavior of an `Analyzer` in a way such that I either don't loose the virtual method lookup or such that it doesn't matter if I do?

Comment: Might be a stupid question to ask but why not override `performAnalysis()` when you're doing `return new AnalyzerDecorator(untweakedAnalyzer)`?

Comment: @Sujay, How should the overridden `performAnalysis` look? In my actual code, `AnalyzerImpl.performAnalysis` is a quite long and complicated method. I don't want to duplicate it :-/

Comment: Maybe you could use the strategy pattern instead.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your decorator isn't called by `performAnalysis` since it has no idea that you decorated the class.

You should probably break `performAnalysis` and `computeValue` into two classes (`Analyzer` with `performAnalysis` and `Calculator` with `computeValue`)

That way, you can decorate them independently, and pass the decorated calculator into `Analyzer` a'la `performAnalysis(Calculator calculator)`.

An example [at IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Db5fv). And yes, it's basically the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in action.

Comment: If you name the Calculator: ComputationStrategy you have a Strategy design pattern.

Comment: This is an interesting option. I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Thanks, especially for the ideone code!

Comment: I've now had a closer look at this. Unfortunately my my `computeValue` methods call each other (like `getTotalCost` calls `getVariableCosts` and `getDirectCosts`). Thus I believe the problem remains in the `Calculator` class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the code of the analyzer object? If so, you could design it to be tweakable by using the strategy pattern.

Alternative (template pattern with kind-of multiple dispatch):

```
abstract class Analyzer {

   public final int ComputeValue () {
      return doComputeValue (this);
   }

   public final string PerformAnalysis () {
      return doPerformAnalysis (this);
   }

   protected abstract int doComputeValue (Analyzer myself);
   protected abstract string doPerformAnalysis (Analyzer myself);
}

class AnalyzerImpl extends Analyzer {

   protected int doComputeValue (Analyzer myself) {
      ...
   }

   protected string doPerformAnalysis (Analyzer myself) {
      return "Result: " + myself.ComputeValue();
   }
}

class AnalyzerDecorator extends Analyzer {
    Analyzer delegate;
    ...
    protected string doPerformAnalysis (Analyzer myself) {
        return delegate.doPerformAnalysis (myself);
    }
    protected int doComputeValue (Analyzer myself) {
        return delegate.doComputeValue (myself);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this approach struck me too, but there are simply too many methods in `Analyzer` for this to be feasible. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Note that you only double the methods in Analyzer, since half of them is final.

Comment: Ah, you changed the interface to an abstract class. That's of course nice.